# If a ring has no zero divisor, Is a every subring of that ring has no zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If a ring has no zero divisor, then is the following statement true?

**Every subring of that ring has no zero divisor**

Comment: Write down the definition of a zero divisor in a ring $R$. Write down what it means for $s$ to be a zero divisor in a subring $S$ of $R$. Compare the two statements.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, so the statement is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring and $S\leq R$. Suppose $s$ is a zero divisor of $S$.

Then $\exists t\in S \text{ st. } st=0$

But this also implies that $s,t$ are zero divisors of $R$, this is a contradiction.